# Is there a way to reduce the time it takes to perform a cleanup?

Tags: cassandra

We are helping 42 nodes Cassandra cluster. For adding a new node to the cluster, we have run clean up on all nodes. We are able to run cleanup for 1 node per day. These actually sum up to 42 days to add a new node in the cluster.

Reason for running only clean up on 1 node per day:

1. cleanup uses a lot of resources (like CPU, memory, and storage) of the node. Adding graphs below.
2. Running high-traffic hours could be a risk to production.
3. one node cleanup takes around 12 hours to complete.

Node Details:

- r5.2xlarge
- CPU: 8
- Memory: 64 GiB
- Storage (EBS gp2 volume): 3584 GiB
- data size
  (45% of storage): around 1612 GiB

cassandra.yml

```
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 256
```

Is there any way to reduce the cleanup time from 42 days?

[image: Load of the Node]
[image: Available Memory]
[image: Cassandra Storage]

Comment: Please add the concurrent_compactors and compactor throughput settings you have in the cassandra.yaml

Comment: Long term, it not be a bad idea to bump up the EBS drives to gp3.  That should help with the IOPS.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the reply. I was able to find the following setting in cassandra.yml. Will this be helpful?
- concurrent_counter_writes: 32
- concurrent_reads: 32
- concurrent_writes: 32
- compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 256

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the reply. We are planning to upgrade ebs to gp3. But do you see any significant process improvement in cleanup with gp3?

Comment: It'll prevent the underlying disk IOPS from becoming a bottleneck.  Shouldn't take nearly as long.

Comment: concurrent_compactors from the yaml will be useful, if its a default of 2, you can push it higher if the IOPs are there

Comment: @Andrew we are having concurrent compactors in the system as 4

Comment: @Andrew What is the value of concurrent compactors I should try?

Comment: @PurushottamBaghel - the compaction throughput is shared amongst concurrent compactors, so even having unlimited throughput, the number of compactors is still then throttling - 4 compactors / 256 mb/sec is ok. If you increase the throughput, consider increasing the number of compactors in the same ratios

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes to perform a cleanup is mostly determined by the amount of data on a node. It makes sense that the more data a node holds, the more time it takes to go through that data to determine whether a partition (record) needs to be cleared out or not.

Of course when there are lots of data, the operation puts a lot of IO load on the disk(s) and it follows that this will also take a lot more resources like CPU and memory.

Consider increasing the number of parallel compaction threads (`concurrent_compactors` in `cassandra.yaml`) if the data disk(s) can handle it particularly if they are backed by fast SSDs. A word of warning that setting this too high can impact other operations such as reads because (for example) all the CPU cores are used for compaction. Too many compaction threads can also cause GC pressure so be aware of that.

Since Cassandra 3.10, it is possible to dynamically get/set the concurrent compactors with [`nodetool getconcurrentcompactors`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/nodetool/getconcurrentcompactors.html) and [`nodetool setconcurrentcompactors`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/nodetool/setconcurrentcompactors.html) ([CASSANDRA-12248](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12248)). These commands do not require a restart compared to setting the property in `cassandra.yaml`.

As a final note, the data will eventually cleared out of nodes during regular compaction runs. If you do not need to urgently reclaim the disk space, there is no rush to complete the cleanup operation. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I want to understand the last point. Let's say I have added a new node and haven't run cleanup for 60 days. It will automatically get cleanup during the regular compaction runs, without extra effort. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: can you please help me with my above doubt? should I not run clean up, if I have added nodes 60 days before the threshold reaches? @Erick Ramirez

Comment: I'll give a quick reply but if you have follow up questions, please start a new post because otherwise, we will end up with a never-ending thread in the comments. There is no way to tell when the "orphaned" data will get cleared out because there are a lot of factors that go into it like how busy your cluster is, hardware, etc. The recommended procedure is to run cleanup after adding nodes to a DC. Cheers!